# can't find Fields for the Product of Coffees and Brewers section

Tags: kentico

I want to see the properties of Coffees and Brewers tried to get to Fields but I couldn't.

The pictures explain what I mean[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x3tP.png)

But I can find Home section easily
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiTZx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties of products are defined in the Modules application under Modules > E-commerce > SKU > Fields. The exact fields for a general product form are in the Alternative Forms > **Product - General properties** form.